# How can I setup varnish for testing purposes?

Tags: varnish

The Varnish docs state that Varnish is configured by default on port 6081, which is "great for testing purposes." https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html

I am running multiple virtual hosts, and while I'm becoming familiar with Varnish, I'd like to keep it on :6081.

I changed my default.vcl .host to be `localhost:80`

I assumed that I could test varnish through :6081, listening to the backend server at the default :80 port all the while the rest of the world would still continue to receive the non varnish version as they normally would on port 80.

However, I keep getting the following error:
"Error 503 Backend fetch failed"

What could I be doing wrong? I went through the tutorial and everything worked as the tutorial indicated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to make sure that the .host parameter in default.vcl was the same as the Listen parameter in httpd.conf. The ip addresses needed to be the same.